# What to do when the question is deleted by the owner while it was answered?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

After spending a large amount of time [answering a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188149/6605), I notice that the author deleted the question after obtaining the answer.

Is it an expected behavior? I believed that we can remove a question only when there were no answers, especially to prevent people to remove their question once they receive an answer. Am I wrong?

Comment: The OP can delete the question if it has only one answer, and that answer has no upvotes (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). I tend to agree that that might not be really desirable though.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Isn't there a time limit? I mean, it's difficult to get upvotes in three minutes (answered: 12:50, deleted: 12:53).

Comment: No time limit as far as I know, I've experienced that once or twice too on Stack Overflow - it's a bit frustrating. Note that you can flag deleted questions (if you have enough rep to see them to begin with), or just flag one of your own posts and explain the situation if you don't. Mods will re-evaluate the deletion and might undo it if they think it's worth it. (And a good answer to a so-so question can make a great deal of difference, maybe with some editing to the question.)

Comment: You might be interested in following this question on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168828/require-a-minimum-rep-to-delete-your-own-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a behaviour we'd want to encourage, and that's exactly why askers can't delete their own questions if there's at least one upvoted answer.

Since the question was deleted almost immediately after you posted your answer (thus you never had a chance to get an upvote) and there were two undelete votes already, I went ahead and undeleted it.